# Unable to save Selected File to directory when not on the development server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

When I am on the development server testing, the following code will save the document in the directory I want it to be in... But when I test it on another computer from the network, the file will not save to the directory. The Directory has "Everyone" Full access but still has this problem.

```
Protected Sub btnSCSoldSheets_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSCSoldSheets.Click
        If fuSCSold.FileName = Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        Else

            Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(fuSCSold.PostedFile.FileName)

           fuSCSold.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ISI/ScoreCard/ScoreCardFiles/") + fileName)

            lblFileNameSCSold.Text = fileName

            generateExcelSheets()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Or what happens?

Comment: No Error. Hard to debug the problem when it's not in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... So silly on my part.

When I copied the website from development to production, I didn't change the physical directory to match what was in production.